# Siri INBillPayIntent not continuing after confirm

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement `INPayBillIntentHandling` in my app. On iOS 11 it goes through fine, and everything works perfectly. On iOS 10.3.1, after the confirm phase, I get a message telling me I'll have to continue in the app.

There's no error messages in my console or crashes showing. No further breakpoints get hit in my UI extensions for it to set itself up, and the handle method is never hit.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what methods may be getting called after confirm that could be affecting my app? All the resolve methods have already been called at this point, and I was under the assumption it would be the `handle` method called next, but alas, I get this error, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have same issue, it seems to be a Apple bug.